# Adding drop menu on tab in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem while adding drop-down menu on this tabs.

How can I add any drop-down menus while using the CSS below?

CSS:

```css
body {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
ul#tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0.3em 0;
}
ul#tabs li { display: inline }
ul#tabs li a {
    color: #42454a;
    background-color: #dedbde;
    border: 1px solid #c9c3ba;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 0.3em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#tabs li a:hover { background-color: #f1f0ee }
ul#tabs li a.selected {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #f1f0ee;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.7em 0.3em 0.38em 0.3em;
}
div.tabContent {
    border: 1px solid #c9c3ba;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #f1f0ee;
}
div.tabContent.hide { display: none }
```

Current HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#about">About JavaScript tabs</a></li>

        <li><a href="#advantages">Advantages of tabs</a></li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Using tabs</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#usage">Sub-Item #7</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item #7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Usage tab and Sub-item tab should be my drop-down menus.

Comment: Do you want to show the Sub-Items on hover? I cannot really figure out what you're trying to do...

Comment: @Danek, why edit the completely irrelevant `<html><head><title></title></head><body>` markup into the question? And why add empty lines into the markup? It didnt help the readability. Copy paste from dirtymarkup.com?

Comment: @davidkonrad, Ohm sure, thanks for telling me, I did not even notice that. I am sorry, it was not the point of my edit :)
I'll pay more attention to those after-mark-up engines next time.
You could notice that it was far not the only thing changed.

Comment: @DonJuwe sorry for my bad english, Sigma solved my problems, thanks to everyone for solving this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    /* CSS FOR DROPDOWN */
    #tabs li{
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
    #tabs a {
        display: block;
    }
    #tabs ul li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    #tabs ul {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: auto;
    }
    #tabs li:hover ul {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9tqks/14/) .

Comment: Thanks again @Sigma, do you have knowledge about javascript i wanted to ask a question if your answer is yes :)

Comment: IMHO I would advice to create a new question tagged with javascript. The idea is that the comments stay relevant to the topic.

Comment: Ok im creating it now :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410422/cant-show-dropmenus-in-tabs this is my question @Sigma

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem visit [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/n6QPT/)

CSS

```
ul#tabs li ul{
    display:none;
}
ul#tabs li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:65px;
}
ul#tabs li:hover ul li{
    float:none;
    margin-bottom:20px;

}
```