# Can not show dropmenus in tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my JavaScript, I can't show my tabs properly.
I can't show tabs in sub tabs, do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Here's one part of my JavaScript Code (the complete code is in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jo_basterd/Pupuh/1/)):

```
function basla() {

    var tabListItems =  document.getElementById('tabs').children;
    for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
        if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
            var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName1( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
            var id = getHash1( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
            tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
            contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
        }
    }

    var i = 0;

    for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
        tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab1;
        tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur(); };
        if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
        i++;
    }

    var i = 0;

    for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabIcerik hide';
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what your problem is: what you are expecting to happen when you do what, and what is happening instead of what you expect?

Comment: `element.children` only selects direct children and no nested ones unless I'm mistaken. You need to get all children recursively.

Comment: I want to do something like this site with my existing code in jsFiddle, http://www.vademecumonline.com.tr/medicineProduct/supravit? Like tab : "Doz". @DorianFM

Comment: as @scenia says, it looks like you want to select the children of your nested `ul`. At the moment the `#advantages` and `#usage` and their links aren't being affected by your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only selecting direct children of your `tabs` element. What you want are descendants (that includes nested elements):

```
var tabListItems =  document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName('*');
```

This will select **all** elements inside the element with ID `tabs` (including the nested `li`s) and not just the first and second `li` as well as the `ul`.

---

The next problem is your empty id for the subtab `li`. In your loop, it will attempt to set `tabLinks[""]`, which of course is impossible and will break the rest of the loop when it gets to that element. You need to catch that case and exclude it:

```
var id = getHash1( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
if (id=="") continue;
```

---

And, lastly, you have a display error at the start, before any tab is selected. That is due to the class `tabIcerik` not being set for the first `li` unless you switch to another element and then back to it. You should either set it upfront or change the following line in the last `for` loop.

```
if ( i != 0 ) {contentDivs[id].className = 'tabIcerik hide';}
else {contentDivs[id].className = 'tabIcerik';}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , how can i change css the title is not showing properly?

Comment: @Jo_bast what do you mean exactly? How is it supposed to show?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jo_basterd/Pupuh/2/ this is fiddle code if you see "About javaScripts Tab" inside the text is not properly shown title is not startin at the beginning of text it is from middle @Scenia

Comment: @Jo_bast Oh, that. That's because the tabs are too big and push the other elements back. You can fix that by increasing the `padding` on your `div.tabIcerik` to something like `0.8em`. The exact number you need to make sure it works might depend on the browser and screen resolution, so going with more (like `1em` or even `1.5em`) can't be too bad.